# XAML binding to a codebehind class property collection is blank (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My codebehind defines a simple class with properties and a constructor as so:

```
public class Question
{
    public string[] Answers
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public int CorrectAnswerIndex
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public Question(string[] answers, int correctIndex)
    {
        this.Answers = answers;
        this.CorrectAnswerIndex = correctIndex;
    }
}
```

There then exists a public object of that type that gets initialised in the window's constructor like so:

```
 CurrentQuestion = new Question(
     new string[] { "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth" }, 2
 );
```

I then have the following XAML in an attempt to print out all of the possible answers from said question.

```
<Grid Margin="150,150,150,150" DataContext="local:CurrentQuestion">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Answers}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

The local namespace is defined previously as the CLR namespace.

However, my list emerges entirely empty. There are no binding errors at runtime.

What's going on here? It seems a simple example that just won't run. I feel I've missed something "obvious."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will look at `ListBox.DataContext` for a property named `Answers`, and try to use that for the `ItemsSource`.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Answers}">
```

`ListBox.DataContext` will be inherited from the parent `Grid`. Unfortunately, the grid's `DataContext` is a string, and strings don't have a property called `Answers`. So the `Binding` can't do anything and gives you `null`.

```
<Grid Margin="150,150,150,150" DataContext="local:CurrentQuestion">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Answers}">
```

XAML implicit conversions are a Do-What-I-Mean thing, thus a source of much confusion. There are times when you can put `local:CurrentQuestion` in an attribute value and have it be taken as a data type -- but this is not one of those times. And a data type isn't what you meant to provide anyway. You wanted a property by that name. But `local:` is a namespace, a literal CLR namespace like `System.Windows.Controls`, not a reference to an object.

Here's how the XAML in a `UserControl` can bind to a property of the `UserControl`. If it's a `Window`, change `UserControl` to `Window`.

```
<Grid Margin="150,150,150,150">
    <ListBox 
        ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentQuestion.Answers, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
```

I'm just guessing that `CurrentQuestion` is a property of the `UserControl`. Let me know if it's somewhere else.

You're also probably going to run into problems when you update `CurrentQuestion`, unless it's a dependency property. If it's a plain old CLR property like this, the UI won't be notified when its value changes:

```
public Question CurrentQuestion { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply! I was beginning to suspect the `local:CurrentQuestion` but didn't know exactly why. I modified the answer you provided to set the context on the whole grid, and it works by setting the binding to `CurrentQuestion` with the `RelativeSource` set. But good grief, it still feels excessive.

Comment: Is there actually a way to use the `local:CurrentQuestion` for this binding, by the way?

Comment: @Dan There's no such thing as `local:CurrentQuestion`. `local:Question` is a data type; `CurrentQuestion` is a property of your `UserControl`. So I'm not sure what you mean by that question.

Comment: I'm confusing how you reference data types versus referencing properties, I think. I'll get there.